# how to setup a programmatically resizable UI in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, programmatically-created

I'm trying to implement a resizable MATLAB UI. But I'm encountering a lot of problems.
In fact, the use of the `normalized` command is compulsory in order to have a window that automatically resize its content. However the 'normalization' of the `uicontrol` items it is not always the same. For instance the `popupmenu` is different from the `text` and `edit`. Moreover the FontSize has another behavior with respect to the previous ones.

Is there a simple tutorial out there in which all this stuff is explained?
I didn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this, I would seriously recommend using Ben Tordoff's GUI Layout Toolbox, [available](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) from the MATLAB Central File Exchange. It gives you GUI resizing almost for free, and much else besides, such as movable panels and well-implemented tab controls. It comes with good documentation, including some simple tutorials and a decent worked-through example.

Ben is from MathWorks consulting group, and the toolbox is used widely by MathWorks when delivering consulting projects. Although it's not a 'supported' MathWorks product, it's very reliable, and it's freely available for you to include in your own projects.

Without this, it's a huge pain to implement resizing on a GUI of any complexity - to do it properly you can't just rely on the `'normalized'` property, you need to implement the `ResizeFcn` callback on everything, and pretty much re-lay everything out each time there's a resize.